# How can I delete bot message in DM?

Tags: python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I'm making a bot with a command that send a file with all the previously executed commands in DM but I can't find a way to delete bot messages. Is there a way to do it or it's just impossible ?

I've tried to make a clear command for this specific case, I've tried this : https://www.reddit.com/r/Discord_Bots/comments/c1tf6t/dm_message_deletion_scriptbot/

but it didn't work for me.

The reddit code :

```py
@client.command()
async def clear_dm(ctx):
    user_dm = (client.get_user(610774599684194307)).dm_channe

    messages_to_remove = 1000

    async for message in user_dm.history(limit=messages_to_remove):
        if message.author.id == client.user.id:
            await message.delete()
            await asyncio.sleep(0.5)
```

The bot messages should be deleted but when I run the command I get an exception `AttributeError: 'ClientUser' object has no attribute 'dm_channel'` the others methodes that I've tried raised similar errors (but I can't show you the code since I've delted it :c)

Comment: Which version of discord.py are you using?

Comment: Discord.py rewritte 1.2.3

Answer (score 0):

`User`s have a [`User.history` attribute](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.User.history) that you can use directly.

```
@client.command()
async def clear_dm(ctx):
    messages_to_remove = 1000

    async for message in client.get_user(610774599684194307).history(limit=messages_to_remove):
        if message.author.id == client.user.id:
            await message.delete()
            await asyncio.sleep(0.5)
```

Comment: It didn't work, the command raises `AttributeError: 'ClientUser' object has no attribute 'history'`

Comment: Is that ID the ID of your bot?

Comment: Yes it is the ID of my bot.

Comment: Are you trying to delete the bots messages in every private channel, or just the private channel it shares with the person who invokes the command?

Comment: I'm trying to delete every bot message in every private channel